# Can we merge [settings] and [campaign-settings]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I can't imagine we need both [settings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings) and [campaign-settings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/campaign-settings). I've set up a synonym request, but if it can be magically made to happen through a meta post, why not?

Comment: Sounds good - trawling through their question lists, they do look like synonyms.

Answer (score 3):

Done, I made campaign-settings the primary.